# Can't find issue that causes variable to be undefined ("Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined)

Tags: javascript, bitmap, undefined, tostring

I'm trying to code a betting/racing game in javascript and I keep running into this error that I can't understand. It's all happening in my ChooseScreen class:

```
constructor(assetManager, stage) {
    super(assetManager, stage);

    this._wagerText = new createjs.BitmapText("", assetManager.getSpriteSheet("uiAssets"));
    this._wagerText.text = this._wagerAmount.toString();
    this._wagerText.letterSpacing = 3;
    this._wagerText.x = 100;
    this._wagerText.y = 20;
    this._screen.addChild(this._wagerText);

    this._wagerAmount=0;

    // custom event
    this._eventScreenComplete = new createjs.Event("contentFinished");
    this._eventScreenPrevious = new createjs.Event("contentBack");

    // add background sprite to container
    let background = assetManager.getSprite("uiAssets");
    background.gotoAndStop("chooseScreen");
    this._screen.addChildAt(background, 0);

    let btn1 = assetManager.getSprite("uiAssets");
    btn1.gotoAndStop("btn1_up");
    btn1.x = 120;
    btn1.y = 110;

    let hitAreaSprite = assetManager.getSprite("uiAssets");
    btn1.buttonHelper = new createjs.ButtonHelper(btn1, 
                                        "btn1_up","btn1_over","btn1_over",
                                        false, hitAreaSprite, "hitArea");
    btn1.on("click", this._onNext, this);
    this._screen.addChild(btn1);

    let btn2 = assetManager.getSprite("uiAssets");
    btn2.gotoAndStop("btn2_up");
    btn2.x = 150;
    btn2.y = 110;

    btn2.buttonHelper = new createjs.ButtonHelper(btn2, 
                                        "btn2_up","btn2_over","btn2_over",
                                        false, hitAreaSprite, "hitArea");
    btn2.on("click", this._onNext, this);
    this._screen.addChild(btn2);

    let btn3 = assetManager.getSprite("uiAssets");
    btn3.gotoAndStop("btn3_up");
    btn3.x = 180;
    btn3.y = 110;

    btn3.buttonHelper = new createjs.ButtonHelper(btn3, 
                                        "btn3_up","btn3_over","btn3_over",
                                        false, hitAreaSprite, "hitArea");
    btn3.on("click", this._onNext, this);
    this._screen.addChild(btn3);

    let btn4 = assetManager.getSprite("uiAssets");
    btn4.gotoAndStop("btn4_up");
    btn4.x = 210;
    btn4.y = 110;

    btn4.buttonHelper = new createjs.ButtonHelper(btn4, 
                                        "btn4_up","btn4_over","btn4_over",
                                        false, hitAreaSprite, "hitArea");
    btn4.on("click", this._onNext, this);
    this._screen.addChild(btn4);
}
update() {
    this._wagerText.text = this._wagerAmount.toString();
}

}
```

I get

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property `toString` of `undefined` at **ChooseScreen.js:78**,

suggesting that `this._wagerText` is `undefined`, yet I cannot figure out why, when I look at the API it shows it is written in the same way I did. Does anyone have any suggestions? Really hoping this isn't a typo I'm stupidly blind to, apologies if so.

Comment: Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: It suggests that `this._wagerAmount` is undefined as that is where you are calling `toString()` on. You are calling `this._wagerAmount.toString()` before you are assigning it a value later on `this._wagerAmount=0;`. `_wagerAmount` is undefined at that point you are calling `toString()`

Comment: Move `this._wagerAmount=0;` line above `this._wagerText.text = this._wagerAmount.toString();`

Comment: The 11th line in your code above is `this._wagerAmount=0;`.  Anything prior to that cannot access `this._wagerAmount` but you try to use it on the 5th line.